# Force a layer not to rotate in a tabbar

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, avfoundation, tabbarcontroller

I have a tabBar app. One of the tabs has a `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, I display in it a camera for reading barcodes. When I rotate the screen, everything rotate (tabbar and image of the camera). What I would like to get is a static image of the camera (disable its rotation) and a tabbar rotating when I rotate the screen.

This is how I add the layer of the camera to the tabBar:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    self.captureSession = AVCaptureSession()

    // This object represents a physical capture device and the properties associated with that device
    let videoCaptureDevice = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDeviceWithMediaType(AVMediaTypeVideo)
    // Is useful for capturing the data from the input device
    let videoInput: AVCaptureDeviceInput

    do {
        videoInput = try AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: videoCaptureDevice)
    } catch {
        self.failed();
        return
    }

    if (self.captureSession.canAddInput(videoInput)) {
        self.captureSession.addInput(videoInput)
    } else {
        self.failed();
        return;
    }

    let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

    if (self.captureSession.canAddOutput(metadataOutput)) {
        self.captureSession.addOutput(metadataOutput)

        metadataOutput.setMetadataObjectsDelegate(self, queue: dispatch_get_main_queue())
        metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN8Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeEAN13Code, AVMetadataObjectTypePDF417Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeUPCECode, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode39Mod43Code, AVMetadataObjectTypeCode93Code,
            AVMetadataObjectTypeCode128Code]
    } else {
        self.failed()
        return
    }

    // Adds the preview layer to display the captured data. Sets the videoGravity to AspectFill so that it covers the full screen
    self.previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: self.captureSession);
    self.previewLayer.frame = self.view.layer.bounds;
    self.previewLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;
    self.view.layer.addSublayer(self.previewLayer)
    self.captureSession.startRunning();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Stop rotation of the view not layer.

```
override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
   return false
}

override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
   return UIInterfaceOrientation.Portrait.rawValue
}
```

This should work.

Comment: Could you please specified more? I think it is a bit more complicate because the view of the camera is in the tabBarController and I want that this tabbar rotates.

Comment: Thanks for the code, but I tried this before and it doesn't work, everything in the screen continue rotating.